# C++ possible to create macros with non-alpha names?

Tags: c++, c++20

Is it possible to make preporcessor to replace an arbitrary string with an arbitrary string?

I would like to replace `{+}` with `{:.{}}`

Comment: No, you can't do that.

Comment: You'd have to use a different macro preprocessor rather than the C++ Preprocessor that comes as part of the C++ toolchain.

Comment: your IDEs search and replace can be considered as "preprocessing" ;)

Comment: Puting aside the direct question, the PP works on tokens, not text. It would be working on the entire string literal, and it can't "edit" parts of that string literal. You might be able to do what you want with a `constexpr` or `consteval` function.

Comment: Why not just replace it? Do you have any reason for wanting to keep `{+}`, other than causing confusion?

Comment: because I have hundreds of `{:.{}}` - not readable

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> C++ possible to create macros with non-alpha names?
>
> I would like to replace {+} with {:.{}}

No, you cannot achieve this using the standard pre-processor. Macro names are identifiers. Identifiers may contain digits (except first char), latin alphabet, underscore, and characters in [XID_Start/XID_Continue](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2020/p1949r4.html#appendix-a---xid_start-code-points) classes.

---

P.S. Consider avoiding pre-processor macros when possible.

Comment: why should avoid preprocessor?

Comment: @BoppityBop It's prone to name collisions because it doesn't understand scopes. It doesn't have a type system that could catch obvious mistakes.

Comment: @BoppityBop it also make debugging more difficult as it hides the actual code the debugger has access to.